# html_safe and non html_safe concatenation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails controller with the following code:

```
class ProgramController < ApplicationController
  def data
    @out="User <i>n<p>ut! </p></i>"+"<br>A bit of<h1>HTML!</h1>".html_safe
  end
end
```

When going into the page, it escapes all the html characters instead of just the characters in the string without `.html_safe`.

The `<%=@out%>` I have in my `erb` file returnes "`User &lt;i&gt;n&lt;p&gt;ut! &lt;/p&gt;&lt;/i&gt;&lt;br&gt;A bit of&lt;h1&gt;HTML!&lt;/h1&gt;`", but I want it to return somthing more like "`User &lt;i&gt;n&lt;p&gt;ut! &lt;/p&gt;&lt;/i&gt;<br>A bit of<h1>HTML!</h1>`".

To make it a bit clearer:

```
Expected output:
User &lt;i&gt;n&lt;p&gt;ut! &lt;/p&gt;&lt;/i&gt;<br>A bit of<h1>HTML!</h1>

Actual output:
User &lt;i&gt;n&lt;p&gt;ut! &lt;/p&gt;&lt;/i&gt;&lt;br&gt;A bit of&lt;h1&gt;HTML!&lt;/h1&gt;

(Output is as shown on view-source)
```

This is obviously a problem with concatenation, as

```
@out="User <i>n<p>ut! </p></i>".html_safe+"<br>A bit of<h1>HTML!</h1>".html_safe
```

causes

```
User <i>n<p>ut! </p></i><br>A bit of<h1>HTML!</h1>
```

to be displayed.

How should I concatenate a html_safe string and a non html_safe string, or escape html characters before concatenation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First lets try to understand what's happening

```rb
to_escape = '<br>'
not_to_escape = '<br>'.html_safe
to_escape.class # String < Object
not_to_escape.class # ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer < String
```

Okay, they're different classes. If we mark the string safe, it's no longer just a string. Makes sense so far.

```rb
total = to_escape + not_to_escape # "<br><br>"
total.class # String < Object
```

Okay, adding them like this gives you a string. No info about anything being safe in here. This happens because you're adding onto `String` so, `String#+` is called which knows nothing about html safety and just adds them together.

Let's try it the other way:

```rb
total = not_to_escape + to_escape # "<br>&lt;br&gt;"
total.class # ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer < String
```

Aha!, now escaping worked correctly and the class is correct, but the order in the result is different. But now we know that adding onto an escaped string does what we want.

Solution:

```rb
total = ''.html_safe + to_escape + not_to_escape # "&lt;br&gt;<br>"
total.class # ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer < String
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `ERB::Util.html_escape` to escape the HTML, something like this:

```
@out = "#{ERB::Util.html_escape('User <i>n<p>ut! </p></i>')}<br>A bit of<h1>HTML!</h1>".html_safe
```

Or you could use `CGI.escapeHTML`:

```
@out = "#{CGI.escapeHTML('User <i>n<p>ut! </p></i>')}<br>A bit of<h1>HTML!</h1>".html_safe
```